# Using java classes with JSP pages

Tags: java, jsp

I am comfortable with Java but I have no experience with JSP pages.

I have a simple login form on my index page which calls a Java class called LoginController to verify the details.

I don't know how to pass the information from LoginController to a new JSP page. I am sure this is a simple line of code but I can't find it.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: You need to use Session's setAttribute and Request Dispatcher. From here you can research and take it forward. :)

Comment: http://www.jsptut.com

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the below method, hope it helps. I normally call the other classes in my servlet and this acts as the controller connecting my java code (model) with the jsp (view), see the below code

`request.setAttribute("attribute_name", result_from_java_class);`

Then i create a dispatcher that sends the result to the jsp page :-

`RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("name_of_the_jsp_file+extension");`

And finally i forward it:

`dispatcher.forward(request, response);`

On the jsp page to retrieve the result i.e information passed from the java class, will be as follows

`request.getAttribute("attribute_name");`

Hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

u can do all in jsp . use JAVA **MVC Framework**

even without that u can perform simple backhand operations using **Servlet**
or else you can use **Java Beans** which is simple business logic implementation 
example for java beans please reffer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_java_beans.htm

example for **Servlet** is given below

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="add" method="post">
        Value 1:<input type="text" name="val1" id="val1"/><br>
        Value 2:<input type="text" name="val2" id="val2"/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br>
        </form>
        <%String sum="";
         sum = (String)request.getAttribute("val3"); %>
        <input type="text" value="<%=sum%>" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>controller.add</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>add</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/add</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**add.java**

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public class add extends HttpServlet {
    String val3;
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String val1=request.getParameter("val1");
        String val2=request.getParameter("val2");
        if(val1 != null && val2 != null)
        val3=""+(Integer.parseInt(val1)+Integer.parseInt(val2));
        else
        val3="";
        request.setAttribute("val3",val3);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response); 

        try {
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Servlet has some scopes (I know 3).
So you can add info to you jsp using info that contains in your scopes.

**request scope**
Object assotiated with request. You can access info during session life.

```
request.setAttribute("attribute_name", result_from_java_class);
```

but sometimes you want to show some info on many pages so if you use request scope you need all time set this attribute.

but you can you **session scope**(assotiate object with the session). Now you can access to object during all you work(session closed when you close site). 
`session.setAttribute("attribute_name", result_from_java_class);`

**Context scope**

A servlet can bind an object attribute into the context by name. Any attribute bound into a context is available to any other servlet that is part of the same Web application. it's also have the same methods

I hope this helps)